# C# Background Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

Let me describe what I am trying to achieve. I am programming in C#.

I have a function (method) DoCalculations(). I want to call this DoCalculations() method recursively. However, in C# I get exception as unhandled exception System.StackOverflow.
So, I am trying to run DoCalculations() method on a back ground thread.

On FORM LOAD event. I have done following:-

```
Thread objThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoCalculations));
```

On START BUTTON CLICK event. I am starting the Thread as follows.

```
 objThread.IsBackground = true;
    objThread.Start();
    while (!objThread.IsAlive)
    {
    }
```

And I intend to run method DoCalculations() continuously with above While Loop.

```
DoCalculations()
{
//some calculations.

}
```

I do get control in DoCalculations() method one time. However, I want to do this every instant.

Please if any one can assist me with regards to back ground thread, or is there any better way to achieve to do parallel computation.

I have used above approach in VB.NET, making me more confused why its not working in C#.NET

Any assistance, comments greatly appreciated.

Thanks
AP

Comment: What do you mean by - `I do get control in DoCalculations() method one time` ?

Comment: Why don't you try fixing the stack overflow exception?

Comment: "I want to call this DoCalculations() method recursively." - Does `DoCalculations` call itself?  Are you sure the termination condition is correct?

Comment: You have misunderstood what ".IsBackground" means.

If .IsBackground is true for a thread, then when that thread's parent process is terminated the thread will also be terminated.

If .IsBackground is false for a thread, then when that thread's parent process is terminated, the process will be kept alive until the thread terminates.

That's the only difference.

Comment: Based on the code you provided the While loop will never end.  So if you are doing something that takes memory, you have a loop that never ends, in a seperate thread.

Answer (score 4):

First, use a background worker, as it is easier to use and faster.

Second, your looping code should go in the background thread.

Here is some code to get you started.

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
bw.RunWorkerAsync();

...

private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while (someCondition)
    {
        DoCalculations();
    }
}
```

EDIT: It sounds like you are just trying to fix a stack overflow, and not knowing how to do so. Forget the multithreading, instead of calling DoCalculations recursively, call it in a loop, and make sure that the loop knows when to terminate. Also, if you don't want to lock up the GUI during this time, then a background thread is better anyway.

Answer (score 2):

[System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) **Provides a mechanism for executing a method at specified intervals.**

*How to Use  in your case....*

```
using System.Threading;
```

Declare timer callback and timer object as follows..

```
 private TimerCallback calculateTimerDelegate = null;
 private System.Threading.Timer calculationTimer = null;
```

And in your Load() event initialize them..

```
calculateTimerDelegate = new TimerCallback(DoCalculation);
calculationTimer = new Timer(calculateTimerDelegate , null, 10000, (1 * 60 * 1000));
```

Now, your method of calculation....

```
DoCalculations()
{
    //some calculations.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run it repeadetly on a background thread, you can use the `System.Threading.Timer` class like this:

```
var timer = new Timer( DoCalculations, null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

This will run your caclulations every second. If you want to adjust the time, change the last `TimeSpan` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Use BackgroundWorker Class

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a stack overflow exception, the way to make it go away will **not** be discovered by introducing multithreading. There's a bug in your recursive code.

Comment: Probably he has the method call itself at the end to make it get called over and over again. Unfortunately, that will cause his stack to overflow quite fast as well.

Comment: agreed. regardless of whether its executing in the same thread or in a different thread. That's my point.