# How to change status of label when a sql server goes down

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server

I have this block of code in my c# application:

```
private bool connected 
public void ChangeStatusa()
{
     if(connected)
     {
       label1.Text="Connected"
     }else{
      label1.Text="Connected"
     }
}
```

I want to auto execute this code when the sql server is disconnected,

and I want to do this work in the background without affecting my application performance.

Essentially, I want to create a system in my application which is responsible for checking the sql server connectivity, and auto change the status when the connection is lost.

Comment: ya i was thinking about this . but in this i have to do continuous  checking . and it will affect application preeminence .

Comment: i think like SqlDependency . i min auto execute code when application loose sql server connection

Comment: Perhaps you're solving the wrong problem. Why are you have db connectivity issues such that this would be useful?

Comment: this application will do some secure transaction . and in fact i want to notify the end user .

Comment: Have you tried consuming the StateChanged event of the SqlConnection? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.statechange.aspx

Comment: ok no i not tried . thanks for that let me do this . but i am connection with sql in my application by using key word . is this ok to create one more connection without closing prev ? @MikeCheel

Answer (score 2):

Are you connecting via tcp?  if so you could try using a straight socket connection with an async receive :  here's some code :

```
class Program
{
    static bool disc = false;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dbtest dt = new dbtest();
        dt.Disconnected += new EventHandler(dt_Disconnected);
        dt.Start("10.1.32.97", 1433);

        while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(disc?"disconnected":"tick");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }

        dt.Stop();
    }

    static void dt_Disconnected(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        disc = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Disconnected");
    }

}

public class dbtest
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[10];
    Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    public event EventHandler Disconnected = null;

    public void Start(string host, int port)
    {
        if(s!=null)
        {
            Stop();
        }

        s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        s.Connect(host, port);
        Console.WriteLine("Connected.");
        s.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallBack, s);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if (s != null)
        {
            s.Close();
            s.Dispose();
            s = null;
        }
    }

    void ReceiveCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Socket s = ar as Socket;

        if (s != null && s.Connected)
        {
            int rcvd = s.EndReceive(ar);

            if (rcvd > 0)
            {
                s.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallBack, s);
                return;
            }
        }

        if(Disconnected!=null)
            Disconnected(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

This is just basic - I'm not sure how long sql server will keep hold of a socket that hasn;t responded.  Maybe add a count - reconnect on disconnect to see if its actually a real disconnect etc etc ...

Comment: Great solution...only concern would be the machine could be up but SQL Server offline or a bad connection string or no rights...seems like the only sure way to know you will have a successful connection is to test that thru SQLConnection object.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a Timer would work for this purpose.  Background thread in an infinite loop with a thread sleep would also work but I dont like anything in an infinite loop.

See

[C# Background Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154747/c-sharp-background-thread)

Here is a fxn to check your connection

```
namespace answer1
{
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

    internal class ConnectionCheck
    {
        private BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

        private void CheckConnection()
        {
            string connetionString = null;
            SqlConnection cnn;
            connetionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=UserName;Password=Password";
            cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
            try
            {
                cnn.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Connection Open ! ");
                cnn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Can not open connection ! ");
            }
        }

        private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                CheckConnection();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is the Main routine you call to execute the background thread
        /// </summary>
        public void RunBackgroundSQLCheck()
        {
            bw.DoWork += this.bw_DoWork;
            bw.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no i tried this and also tried BackgroundWorker. they both are affecting application performance.

Comment: Thats unfortunate...otherwise...just check it at the point you commit a SQL call and rollback as needed.